# Is the implementation of the hazard pointer in C++ Concurrency in Action flawed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, stdatomic

I am reading the second edition of C++ Concurrency in Action. The code below is from Listing 7.6. It implements `pop()` for the stack using hazard pointers.

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
  std::atomic<void*>& hp = get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();
  node* old_head = head.load();  // #1
  do {
    node* temp;
    do {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);        // #2
      old_head = head.load();    // #3
    } while (old_head != temp);  // #4
  } while (old_head &&
           !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next));
  hp.store(nullptr);
  // ...
}
```

The book explains the role of the inner loop:

> You have to do this in a `while` loop to **ensure that the `node` hasn't been deleted between the reading of the old `head` pointer `#1` and the setting of the hazard pointer `#2`**. During this window no other thread knows you're accessing this particular node. Fortunately, if the old `head` node is going to be deleted, **`head` itself must have changed, so you can check this and keep looping until you know that the `head` pointer still has the same value you set your hazard pointer to `#4`**.

According to the implementation of `pop`, if another thread deletes the head node by `pop` between `#1` and `#2`, then `head` will be modified to the new node.

What confuses me is, can the modification of `head` by other threads be seen by the current thread in time? For example, if the new value of `head` has not been propagated to the current thread, then `#1` and `#3` will still read the same value (the old value), causing the inner `while` loop to exit and in turn the outer `while` loop accessing `old_head->next`, resulting in undefined behavior.

I've searched stackoverflow for some answers. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833218/15905455) says

> The default memory ordering of `std::memory_order_seq_cst` provides a single global total order for all `std::memory_order_seq_cst` operations across all variables. **This doesn't mean that you can't get stale values**, but it does mean that the value you do get determines and is determined by where in this total order your operation lies.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971838/c-atomics-reading-stale-value#comment129026721_73048822) says

> Every atomic variable has its own modification order that all threads can agree on, but that only serializes modifications, not reads. The coherency requirements involving reads **just guarantee that if you've seen one value in the modification order, you can't see an earlier one**.

But [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) says

> Each `memory_order_seq_cst` operation `B` that loads from atomic variable `M`, observes one of the following:
>
> - the result of the *last* operation `A` that modified `M`, which *appears before B in the single total order*
>
> ...

So what exactly should the answer to my question be?

Also, if a weaker ordering (like release-acquire or relaxed) is used here, would the above problem arise?

---

Here is the code of `pop`:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
  std::atomic<void*>& hp = get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();
  node* old_head = head.load();  // #1
  do {
    node* temp;
    do {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);        // #2
      old_head = head.load();    // #3
    } while (old_head != temp);  // #4
  } while (old_head &&
           !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next));
  hp.store(nullptr);  // Clear hazard pointer once you're finished
  std::shared_ptr<T> res;
  if (old_head) {
    res.swap(old_head->data);
    if (outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head)) // Check for hazard pointers referencing a node before you delete it.
      reclaim_later(old_head);
    else
      delete old_head;
    delete_nodes_with_no_hazards();
  }
  return res;
}
```

`pop()` pops the node pointed to by `head` and frees it when no hazard pointer points to it. Modifying the `head` is achieved by `compare_exchange_strong`.

Comment: How is the hazard pointer `hp` used elsewhere in the code?  It can have no effect on this function itself, because it is only written and never read.

Comment: When thinking about lock-free atomic programming, I find it helpful to forget about the word "time" and everything related to it.  The whole point of the memory model is that it is defined in terms of orders which in principle have nothing to do with the clock on the wall (though in real life they probably do).  I presume the "stale" in the first quoted answer means "you may fail to load a value which was stored earlier with respect to real time", but that should be irrelevant, as unless you are doing real-time programming, your program should not care how real time passes.

Comment: @NateEldredge I only selected part of the code because I don't think the rest is relevant to the problem. `hp` is used in the rest of `pop`.

Comment: @NateEldredge But if the previously stored value is not read, it can cause the problem I describe. Is this possible?

Comment: I think its use *is* relevant.  The code here seems to be trying to preserve some invariant relationship between `head` and the hazard pointer.  It's not clear to me from this code alone, or your excerpt of the explanation, what that invariant is supposed to be.  But we could perhaps infer it by looking at whatever code elsewhere actually relies on that invariant.  It can't be the code here because its behavior is totally unaffected by the value of the hazard pointer.  Once we know what the invariant is, we can see whether this code correctly preserves it.

Comment: Thread safety is a relational property; two pieces (or more) of code are thread safe relative to each other.  Asking if a single thread is thread safe is nonsense: at best an implied family of other threads is assumed. You have shared one piece of code.  You need the code where head is modified, and possibly where hp is used, to determine relatove thread safety.  This inability for seperate analysis is why concurrency is fundamentally hard.

Comment: @NateEldredge OK, I'll post the full code. But I think I can briefly describe the relationship between `hp` and `old_head`. The code requires that `hp` and `old_head` must have the same value, because only if there is a `hp` pointing to a node, the node will not be deleted, and thus the pointer will be valid. So, to safely dereference `old_head`, `hp` must be guaranteed to have the same value as it.

Comment: "`hp` must be guaranteed to have the same value as it."  But *when*?  All we ever can actually observe is whether some load of `hp` and some load of `head` return the same value.  Those two loads can't be simultaneous, so it is crucial to know how they are ordered with respect to each other.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes. From what I understand, when we try to dereference `old_head`, we must ensure that the value of `hp` is the same as it, not `head` but `old_head`, because `old_head` is the node to be deleted by the current thread. But IMHO this seems to have strayed from my question.

Comment: Well, your question was "is the code flawed", which can't be answered without seeing both sides of it.  But I think I see what you are asking.  It is possible that another thread stored to `head` (call the store W) "between" #1 and #3 with respect to real time, yet #1 and #3 both return the same value.  But if so, then W must come *after* #3 in the sequentially consistent total ordering, and as such, also comes after #2.  This would allow us to deduce that the other thread will not free the pointer which we loaded at #1 and #3.

Comment: As you see, where W occurred in real time is simply irrelevant.  The values observed by loads #1 and #3 tell us something about where W appears in the total order, and that's all that matters for the purposes of describing the program's observable behavior.

Comment: And as a quick comment, sequential consistency is essential here.  Acquire/release, much less relaxed, cannot stop StoreLoad reordering, and so could not ensure that #2 and #3 are observed in that order by other threads, which is critical for the algorithm.  I'll try to post a more complete answer later.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks. I look forward to your answer. But I found [a project](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/1768#issuecomment-554823949) that once caused a bug by using load operations with seq-cst order. Thread A modifies an atomic variable and then sleeps. Thread B reads the atomic variable and determines whether A should be woken up based on the value. However, because the Load operation did not read the updated value in time, thread B did not wake up A.

Comment: @NateEldredge The project then replaced the Load operation with fetch_add(0) to [fix the bug](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/commit/bf56b50a855f5d1f08f15dce0f4138e17cfa6f6e). I think the problem that arises here is the same as the one I describe. How to explain this?

Comment: @Pluto: Well, the stack code in your question doesn't have a problem at all AFAICS, so it can't be the same problem.  I haven't yet worked out what the tokio bug actually was, and on first impression, I'm skeptical that `fetch_add(0)` actually fixed it.  It may very well have *hidden* the bug so it no longer appears in practice, at least on whatever compilers and CPU architectures they tested, because real machines often provide stronger ordering guarantees than the abstract memory model requires.  But my sneaking suspicion is that in theory, their unwanted race can still occur.

Comment: On x86 for instance, every atomic read-modify-write is a full barrier, so a `fetch_add(0)`, even if it were relaxed, would have similar effect to a seq_cst fence.  But the memory model doesn't guarantee that, and on other architectures it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think it's flawed.

To verify that the algorithm is correct, let me annotate a few more lines of code here.  I rewrote line 8 to make it clear that it does a load from the other thread's hazard pointer.

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
  std::atomic<void*>& hp = get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();
  node* old_head = head.load();  // #1
  do {
    node* temp;
    do {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);        // #2
      old_head = head.load();    // #3
    } while (old_head != temp);  // #4
  } while (old_head &&
           !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next));
                                 // #5 deref of old_head
                                 // #6 the compare_exchange
  hp.store(nullptr);             // #7 
  std::shared_ptr<T> res;
  if (old_head) {
    res.swap(old_head->data);
    if (other_thread_hp.load() == old_head)
                                 // #8
      reclaim_later(old_head);
    else
      delete old_head;           // #9
    delete_nodes_with_no_hazards();
  }
  return res;
}
```

---

**Informal justification**

Suppose thread A is trying to safely dereference `old_head` while Thread B wants to delete it.

It is entirely possible that, for instance, the `compare_exchange_strong` in thread B line 6 (B6 for short) occurs between the loads A1 and A3 with respect to real time, but does not become visible to thread A until later.

However, we have sequential consistency.  Every thread must observe the operations B6 and B8 in that order.  So if B6 didn't become visible to A until after A3, then B8 cannot become visible to A until later still, and by that time, store A2 will have taken effect.  In other words, load B8 must observe all stores that preceded A3, including in particular A2.  So either B8 will return the non-null hazard pointer from A, in which case the delete is not done; or else it returns `nullptr`, which can only happen if store A7 has become visible, and by that time the dereference A5 has already completed.

Thus, if there can be a delay between when B6 is executed and when it becomes globally visible, then the implementation must arrange that all subsequent operations in thread B, including in particular B8, are stalled until after B6 does become visible.  On present-day hardware, the typical reason for such a delay is that the store at B6 went into a store buffer.  So to ensure sequential consistency, the compiler has to insert a barrier instruction between B6 and B8, which will wait for the store buffer to drain and commit to coherent L1 cache before continuing on.

**Edit**: To your question in comments about delaying non-atomic operations: Things are complicated a bit because B6 is a read-modify-write, but for memory ordering purposes, you can think of it as consisting of a load (B6L) and a store (B6S), both of which are `seq_cst`.  For purposes of ordering with respect to non-`seq_cst` operations, including all non-atomic operations, a `seq_cst` store is simply a release store, and a `seq_cst` load is merely an acquire load.  So indeed, non-atomic operations that follow B6S do not have to "stall" and, unless otherwise restricted, may become visible before B6S does.  (They cannot become visible before B6L however, because it is acquire.)

But by the same token, B8 is acquire.  This *does* require later operations, including non-atomic operations such as B9, to stall until after B8 has become visible.  (Here B9 is on one side of a conditional branch which depends on the value loaded by B8, but without the acquire barrier, it could still start doing loads speculatively.)  So indeed, the net result is that B9 must become visible only after B6S, because B9 must wait for B8 which must wait for B6S.

---

**Formal proof of correctness**

Remember that the C++ memory model has no concept of "in time" or "stale"; everything is defined in terms of abstract orderings.  Here all the atomic operations are `seq_cst` by default, so there is a total order on all of them, with coherency rules ensuring that they observe each other in all the usual ways.

We'll write A1, B1, etc, for operation #1 as executed by Threads A or B respectively.  Also, let `hpA, hpB` be the hazard pointers belonging to the corresponding threads.  Let `H0` be the value of `head` going into the code here, which both threads initially load as their `old_head`, and `H1`, `H2` the addresses of the following nodes.

We want to make sure that A5 happens before B9.  If A5 is going to dereference pointer `H0`, it must be that loads A1, A3 both returned `H0`, which means that A2 stored `H0` to `hpA`.  (Or if A1 didn't, then both the second-to-last and last iterations of A3 must have loaded `H0`; either way the conclusion is that A2 stored `H0`.)

Likewise, if B6 is going to delete `H0`, it must be that B6 loaded `H0` from `head` and stored `H1`.  So if both these conditions hold, then A3 precedes B6 in the total order (or A3 < B6 for short); otherwise A3 would have loaded `H1` instead.  By transitivity, and the fact that the seq_cst total order is consistent with sequencing (program order), we have A2 < A3 < B6 < B8.

Now since it is a total order, either A7 < B8 or A7 > B8.

- If A7 < B8, then B8 observes `nullptr` stored by A7.  Since A7 was a release store (implied by `seq_cst`), and B8 was an acquire load that observed the value stored by A7, we have that A7 happens before B8.  By sequencing A5 happens before A7, and B8 happens before B9, so A5 happens before B9.  Thus B9 will delete `H0`, but A5 has already finished dereferencing it and there is no data race or use-after-free.
- If A7 > B8, then we have A3 < B8 < A7.  So B8 must observe the store A3 (which stored `H0` to `hpA`), and it must not observe store A7 which stored `nullptr`.  So in this case B8 loads the value `H0`, which equals thread B's `old_head`, and
  the deletion of `H0` is deferred by thread B.  Thus the dereference at A5 was safe, because `H0` is not being deleted at all.

---

Acquire-release ordering would not be good enough for this algorithm.  Informally, acquire-release forbids LoadLoad, StoreStore, and LoadStore reordering, but still allows for StoreLoad reordering.  As such, A2 could become visible after A3, which would be disastrous.  **Edit**: And to your comment below, yes, B6S could also become visible after B8 and B9 (with B7 becoming visible later still).

Relaxed ordering would be even worse; for instance, A7 could become visible before A5 has completed.

Comment: *the implementation must arrange that all subsequent operations in thread B, including in particular B8, are stalled until after B6 does become visible.* Does the delayed operation include other non-atomic operations? For example, the (possible) `delete` operation at `#9` here.

Comment: Also, if a weaker ordering is used, will the operations after B6 still be delayed if B6's modifications to the head are not seen by A1 and A3? That is, is it possible for A to see the deleted node first, and then see the modification result of B6?

Comment: @Pluto: Regarding both comments, see edits in the question.