# How to copy/set a volatile std::string?

Tags: c++, string, volatile, stdstring

How can I copy a `volatile std::string`? There is no copy constructor for volatile, nor does something like `c_str` allow volatile access. `operator=` also doesn't seem to allow setting a volatile. It seems like `std::string` is simply unusable as a volatile object. Is this intended, or am I missing some way to use it?

NOTE: I have easy workarounds, I just came upon the issue while trying to use string in some low-level code.

Comment: volatile std::string is very wrong. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `volatile` means that the object lives outside the C++ memory model. I'd say that that notion is almost entirely unusable for a dynamic container.

Comment: I was testing to see if I could replace a malloc/free call in my compiler's JIT. It's part of the abort handling (using setjmp). Totally undefined territory as far as the standard is concerned, it just made me curious about volatile strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, none of the member functions on `std::string` are marked `volatile`, so you can't perform any operations on a `volatile std::string`. I think the only option would be to cast away `volatile`ness and perform operations on the result, as shown here:

```
const_cast<std::string&>(myVolatileString) = "Now I'm different!"
```

Fundamentally, though, you probably shouldn't be making a `volatile std::string`. `volatile` is appropriate for objects that might be mutated by external sources or changed by multiple threads. This first case is pretty unusual and would require some very special hardware that knew the layout of `std::string`. The second is unsafe because `std::string` isn't thread-safe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does the const_cast however remove the volatile nature of the object? That is, does it make the access as though it wasn't declared "volatile"?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y- Yes. It returns a non-`volatile` reference to the object, which can then be treated like any non-`volatile` string.

Comment: @BЈовић- `volatile`, in C++11, indicates to the compiler that the value may be written to by another thread without locking, so the compiler should not try to optimize away reads of the object.

Comment: @templatetypedef I've heard otherwise, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8819095/395760). Yes, it means "don't optimize away reads", but AFAIK a plain (for example) `int` won't be read or written atomically so you get UB anyway. Are you sure you're not confusing C++ `volatile` with Java `volatile`, which *does* do some of these things?

Comment: It's not the thread aspect of volatile I'm interested in. I'm using setjmp/longjmp and want to prevent optimization across that boundary.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y- Oh boy... that's a whole other can of worms. `volatile` doesn't protect you from that. The C++ spec says "The function signature longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val) has more restricted behavior in this
International Standard. If any automatic objects would be destroyed by a thrown exception transferring
control to another (destination) point in the program, then a call to longjmp(jbuf, val) at the throw
point that transfers control to the same (destination) point has undefined behavior."