# Where are the statement of or the foundations for the "as if" rule in the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, as-if

After a little google search (for instance, `site:eel.is "as if rule"`) I couldn't find a proper place where the so called "as if" rule is clearly stated in the C++ standard. All I could find is that in those places within the standard where it is invoked, the `intro.execution` reference is given.

But [`intro.execution`](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution) doen't seem to clearly reference any general form of this rule. I'm probably missing something subtle here, but can you point me to the place, or places, where a precise normative understanding of the rule is conveyed? Maybe the whole `intro.execution` is indeed intended to convey what we call as the "as if" rule in the wild? I confess that I've just skimmed through it.

I'm using [this website](https://eel.is/c++draft/) to navigate through the working draft of the standard.

The definition of the "as if" rule can be found, for instance in the [cppreference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), as something to the effect that compilers are allowed to perform transformations on programs as long as some constraints are met, for optimizations reasons, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition for "as if" rule is given in the footnote to 4.1.1/1. See http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#footnote-4:

> This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an
>   implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this document
>   as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far
>   as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program. For
>   instance, an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an
>   expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no
>   side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are
>   produced.

Answer (score 3):

From a different [Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), it would appear that the section you refer to in your link *actually is* the "as-if" rule (see the footnote #5):

> **1.9 Program execution [intro.execution]**
>   The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic
>   abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on
>   the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need
>   not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather,
>   conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the
>   observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained
>   below.<sup>5</sup>.
>   ... 
>   *5) This provision is sometimes called the
>   “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any
>   requirement of this International Standard as long as the result is as
>   if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from
>   the observable behavior of the program. For instance, an actual
>   implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can
>   deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting
>   the observable behavior of the program are produced.*

PS: One thing I found 'interesting' in this quoted document is the index entry for "as-if rule":

```
program execution, 8–11
    abstract machine, 8
    as-if rule, see as-if rule
```

Comment: Concerning the index entry, maybe the link should have been to "::as-if rule".

Comment: This answer is also great. As I had to chose one of them, I accepted the answer by SergeyA, as it deals with the current draft.