# Correct usage of volatile with std::atomic_ref<T>

Tags: c++, atomic, volatile, mmap, atomicreference

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the correct usage of `std::atomic_ref<int>` with `volatile`.

Naively there are three possibilities:

```
std::atomic_ref<volatile int> ref1;
volatile std::atomic_ref<int> ref2;
volatile std::atomic_ref<volatile int> ref3;
```

When and do we want to use each one? The use-case I'm interested in is MMIO.

Comment: What is the problem you are solving?

Comment: I have a mmap'd struct, which is used as an IPC fifo. Both reads and writes have order requirements. I'm considering relying on the `std::memory_order` of the atomic accesses to implement the memory barriers.

Comment: If the value is memory-mapped to hardware and *all* writes, even identical ones, are important, then `volatile` is needed, otherwise simply `std::atomic_ref<int> ref2` in combination with a default `memory_order::seq_cst` should be enough to guarantee ordering.

Comment: @rustyx what do you mean by identical writes: a write to the same memory location, or a write of the same value to the same memory location?

Comment: @rustyx I'm not sure I completely follow why I wouldn't need `volatile` given that a read from the mmap'd struct will tell me the current fifo capacity.

Comment: Using memory mapped between processes for IPC doesn't need `volatile`, `std::atomic` is sufficient.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Even if I have to read from the value to check the capacity of the fifo?

Comment: That's what atomics are for.

Comment: Is there then a scenario where I would want a `std::atomic<volatile int>`?

Comment: Interesting discussion on volatile and atomics https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1231#issuecomment-400704968

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `std::atomic<T>`, `std::atomic_ref<T>` does not have `volatile`-qualified methods. So, you probably can't do much with a `volatile std::atomic_ref<T>` (whether T is itself volatile or not).

This makes sense given the [quote](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref)

> Like language references, constness is shallow for atomic_ref - it is possible to modify the referenced value through a const atomic_ref object.

Assuming cv-qualification is somewhat consistent, a shallowly-volatile atomic_ref is unlikely to be useful, and definitely isn't what you're asking for.

So, you want

```
std::atomic_ref<volatile int>
```

Note that it *may* be sufficient to just use `std::atomic_ref<int>`, but since the standard doesn't make any explicit guarantees about MMIO, you should probably consult your compiler documentation and/or check the code it generates.

Depending on `std::atomic` in this way is at least not portable. Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595602/212858) and its [linked paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0062r1.html) mention some ways in which `std::atomic` may be inadequate - you can check whether these are actual problems for you.

Comment: Good point regarding the lack of the volatile methods, I hadn't noticed. I was also leaning towards `std::atomic_ref<volatile int>`. Thanks