# atomic_store of shared_ptr of interface

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, atomic

I am trying to set the value of a shared_ptr in an atomic way:

```
shared_ptr<Base> a = std::make_shared<Derived>();
....
shared_ptr<Base> b;
std::atomic_store(&b,a); // Error here
```

I got the error message "'std::shared_ptr< Base >' is not derived from 'volatile std::atomic<_ITp>'"

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Basically the way to do this in a thread safe way is to use a mutex. You may want to wrap the shared pointer and mutex in a class to guarantee that nobody can set the shared pointer without grabbing the mutex.

Comment: @NirFriedman mutex doesn't guarantee that the access is volatile, so not good enough.

Comment: Uhm what? Volatile probably doesn't mean what you think it does, you should read up on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496692/should-stdatomic-be-volatile.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still what I want to achieve is "inter-thread synchronization", meaning var value should be seen the same among threads. Does shared_ptr have this feature?

Comment: The quotes are not necessary. Mutexes are perhaps the simplest way to achieve inter-thread communication. Wrapping a variable in a mutex would mean that only one thread could read or write the mutex at a time. Each thread is therefore guaranteed to always see a consistent value of the variable. It does not matter whether that varaible is a shared_ptr or something else.

Comment: @NirFriedman pls correct me if I am wrong. As a long time user of mutex, I understand that it only helps to lock the Content inside its guarded block (its impl is self-explanatory). However, it does NOT guarantee that changes to the content is instantly seen by other threads (volatile feature)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "instantly". That is not what volatile does. Volatile basically just says that the program cannot elide any reads or writes for that variable. With a mutex, within the lock things can be elided but that doesn't matter because only one thread is there. mutex's are required to sync so no reads/writes can be elided across the mutex boundary. tl; dr mutexes are fine for this and I still think there is some kind of lack of clarity about what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specialization of atomic_store for std::shared_ptr, see

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

And by modern compilers (say, GCC 5) the code you provide is compiled just fine. So I suppose you compiler is not fully support C++11 (just like GCC 4.x, that lacks the specialization).

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the issue.