# Atomic operation propagation/visibility (atomic load vs atomic RMW load)

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic, propagation, memory-visibility

**Context**

I am writing a thread-safe [protothread/coroutine library](https://github.com/sm2coin/libcr) in C++, and I am using atomics to make task switching lock-free. I want it to be as performant as possible. I have a general understanding of atomics and lock-free programming, but I do not have enough expertise to optimise my code. I did a lot of researching, but it was hard to find answers to my specific problem: *What is the propagation delay/visiblity for different atomic operations under different memory orders?*

**Current assumptions**

I read that changes to memory are propagated from other threads, in such a way that they might become visible:

1. in different orders to different observers,
2. with *some* delay.

I am unsure as to whether this delayed visibility and inconsistent propagation applies only to non-atomic reads, or to atomic reads as well, potentially depending on what memory order is used. As I am developing on an x86 machine, I have no way of testing the behaviour on weakly ordered systems.

**Do all atomic reads always read the latest values, regardless of the type of operation and the memory order used?**

I am pretty sure that all *read-modify-write* (RMW) operations *always* read the most recent value written by any thread, regardless of the memory order used. The same seems to be true for *sequentially consistent* operations, but only if all other modifications to a variable are also *sequentially consistent*. Both are said to be slow, which is not good for my task. If not all atomic reads get the most recent value, then I will have to use RMW operations just for reading an atomic variable's latest value, or use atomic reads in a while loop, to my current understanding.

**Does the propagation of writes (ignoring side effects) depend on the memory order and the atomic operation used?**

*(This question only matters if the answer to the previous question is that not all atomic reads always read the most recent value. Please read carefully, I do not ask about the visibility and propagation of side-effects here. I am merely concerned with the value of the atomic variable itself.)* This would imply that depending on what operation is used to modify an atomic variable, it would be guaranteed that any following atomic read receives the most recent value of the variable. So I would have to choose between an operation guaranteed to always read the latest value, or use relaxed atomic reads, in tandem with this special write operation that guarantees instant visibility of the modification to other atomic operations.

Comment: Please do not put the answer in the question. Post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: What do you mean by: for non atomic operations?

Comment: @curiousguy Normal read operations (i.e. of ints) are not guaranteed to be atomic and might read torn values, even if all writes are atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion, here are my findings: First, let's define what an atomic variable's *latest value* means: In wall-clock time, the very latest write to an atomic variable, so, from an external observer's point of view. If there are multiple simultaneous last writes (i.e., on multiple cores during the same cycle), then it doesn't really matter which one of them is chosen.

1. Atomic loads of any memory order have no guarantee that the *latest* value is read. This means that writes have to propagate before you can access them. This propagation may be out of order with respect to the order in which they were executed, as well as differing in order with respect to different observers.

   ```cpp
   std::atomic_int counter = 0;

   void thread()
   {
       // Imagine no race between read and write.
       int value = counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
       counter.store(value+1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
       std::async(thread);
   ```

   In this example, according to my understanding of the specs, even if no read-write executions were to interfere, there could still be multiple executions of `thread` that read the same values, so that in the end, `counter` would not be 1000. This is because when using normal reads, although threads are guaranteed to read modifications to the same variable in the correct order (they will not read a new value and on the next value read an older value), they are not guaranteed to read the globally latest written value to a variable.

   This creates the *relativity* effect (as in Einstein's physics) that every thread has its own "truth", and this is exactly why we need to use sequential consistency (or acquire/release) to restore causality: If we simply use relaxed loads, then we can even have broken causality and apparent time loops, which can happen because of instruction reordering in combination with out-of-order propagation. Memory ordering will ensure that those separate realities perceived by separate threads are at least causally consistent.
2. Atomic read-modify-write (RMW) operations (such as exchange, compare_exchange, fetch_add,…) are guaranteed to operate on the latest value as defined above. This means that propagation of writes is forced, and results in one universal view on the memory (if all reads you make are from atomic variables using RMW operations), independent of threads. So, if you use `atomic.compare_exchange_strong(value,value, std::memory_order_relaxed)` or `atomic.fetch_or(0, std::memory_order_relaxed)`, then you are guaranteed to perceive one global order of modification that encompasses all atomic variables. *Note that this does not guarantee you any ordering or causality of non-RMW reads.*

   ```cpp
   std::atomic_int counter = 0;

   void thread()
   {
       // Imagine no race between read and write.
       int value = counter.fetch_or(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
       counter.store(value+1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
       std::async(thread);
   ```

   In this example (again, under the assumption that none of the `thread()` executions interfere with each other), it seems to me that the spec forbids `value` to contain anything but the globally latest written value. So, `counter` would always be 1000 in the end.

**Now, when to use which kind of read?**

If you only need causality within each thread (there might still be different views on what happened in which order, but at least every single reader has a causally consistent view on the world), then atomic loads and acquire/release or sequential consistency suffice.

But if you also need fresh reads (so that you must never read values other than the globally (across all threads) latest value), then you should use RMW operations for reading. Those alone do not create causality for non-atomic and non-RMW reads, but all RMW reads across all threads share the exact same view on the world, which is always up to date.

**So, to conclude**: Use atomic loads if different world views are allowed, but if you need an *objective reality*, use RMWs to load.

Comment: In very short, as RMW `or 0` highly likely is atomic load, it may be executed the same way :-)

Comment: I don't think so. RMWs behave completely different from loads, as far as I can tell.

Comment: With relativity, if some event X is the past of A, and A sends a signal to B, when B receives the signal, X is in the past of B at that time. This may not hold for MT programming.

Comment: "_then you are guaranteed to perceive one global order of modification that encompasses all atomic variables_" I'm pretty sure that isn't the intent of the std

Comment: RMW operations are per specification forced to behave like this (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: @RmbRT Which part of the spec says that?

Comment: @curiousguy I did not read the official specs. I read the descriptions at cppreference.com and cplusplus.com (which are based on the specs) and many other, less notable sources (which I can't recall right now). Combined with previous knowledge and some thinking of my own, this is the conclusion I came to. This might be wrong, but I see no other way of interpreting the information I have at hand.

Comment: @RmbRT Could you describe an example of what you think is guaranteed for RMW that isn't for R then W? (that doesn't involved the fact the value isn't changed in the middle of course)

Comment: @curiousguy I added examples.

Comment: @RmbRT Would the program be less well specific w/o `fetch_or(0,...)`? IOW what executions are legal for `load(o)` that isn't legal for `fetch_or(0,o)`?

Comment: @curiousguy In my example, in thread 1, you can load counter = 0, then write counter=1, and in thread 2, even if it happens after 1 has been written, you may still load counter = 0, and then write it to 1. This is because there is no guarantee for an atomic load to read the absolutely latest value written to the variable. For fetch_or, you cannot read a value older than the latest write, so you cannot load 0 after 1 has been written. Using an RMW to load a value forces the propagation of the latest write to the CPU that is performing the RMW operation.

Answer (score 9):

#### Is atomic lock-free ?

First of all, let's get rid of the elephant in the room:  using `atomic` in your code doesn't guarantee a lock-free implementation. `atomic` is only an enabler for a lock-free implementation.  [`is_lock_free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) will tell you if it's really lock-free for the C++ implementation and the underlying types that you are using.

#### What's the latest value ?

The term "latest" is very ambiguous in the world of multithreading.  Because what is the "latest" for one thread that might be put asleep by the OS, might no longer be what is the latest for another thread that is active.

[`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) only guarantees is a protection against racing conditions, by ensuring that [R, M and RMW](http://modernescpp.com/index.php/synchronization-and-ordering-constraints) performed on one atomic in one thread are performed atomically, without any interruption, and that all other threads see either the value before or the value after, but never what's in-between.  So `atomic` synchronize threads by creating an order between concurrent operations on the same atomic object.

You need to see every thread as a parallel universe with its own time and that is unaware of the time in the parallel universes.  And like in quantum physics,  the only thing that you can know in one thread about another thread is what you can observe (i.e. a "happened before" relation between the universes).

This means that you should not conceive multithreaded time as if there would be an absolute "latest" across all the threads. You need to conceive time as relative to the other threads.  This is why atomics don't create an absolute latest, but only ensure a sequential ordering of the successive states that an atomic will have.

#### Propagation

The propagation doesn't depend on the memory order nor the atomic operation performed.  [memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) is about sequential constraints on non-atomic variables around atomic operations that are seen like fences.  The best explanation of how this works is certainly [Herb Sutters presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4), that is definitively worth its hour and half if you're working on multithreading optimisation.

Although it is possible that a particular C++ implementation could implement some atomic operation in a way that influences propagation, you cannot rely on any such observation that you would do, since there would be no guarantee that propagation works in the same fashion in the next release of the compiler or on another compiler on another CPU architecture.

#### But does propagation matter ?

When [designing lock-free algorithms](https://www.memsql.com/blog/common-pitfalls-in-writing-lock-free-algorithms/), it is tempting to read atomic variables to get the latest status.  But whereas such a read-only access is atomic, the action immediately after is not. So the following instructions might assume a state which is already obsolete (for example because the thread is send asleep immediately after the atomic read).

Take `if(my_atomic_variable<10)` and suppose that you read 9. Suppose you're in the best possible world and 9 would be the absolutely latest value set by all the concurrent threads.  Comparing its value with `<10` is not atomic,  so that when the comparison succeeds and `if` branches, `my_atomic_variable` might already have a new value of 10. And this kind of problems might occur regardless of how fast the propagation is, and even if the read would be guaranteed to always get the latest value. And I didn't even mention the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) yet.

The only benefit of the read is to avoid a data race and UB.  But if you want to synchronize decisions/actions across threads, you need to use an RMW, such [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (e.g. [`atomic_compare_exchange_strong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange)) so that the ordering of atomic operations result in a predictable outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you please elaborate more on the part about how different atomic operations have different visibility guarantees (the documentation on RMW operations suggest that there in fact exists a single "latest value", which is the one RMW operations observe).

Comment: @RmbRT suppose you have 3 threads.  1wants to write on an atomic x, 2 wants to RMW on x, 3 wants to read.  If the ordering of the operations is first 1, then 2 will perform rmw on x based on the value set by 1. If the ordering is first 2, then rmw will be performed but value will be overwritten by 1.  In both case,  you have no guarantee about the value that is read by 3.  You could perfectly have 3 reading the  value set by 1, then is set asleep, then 2 changes the value of x,  but then 3 awakes and continues processing of non-atomic ops with an outdated value.

Comment: Is there a different speed at which writes propagate to different processors? And is the "sees the last value" guarantee also valid for normal atomic reads? So, in your example, could 3 read 1's value, even if 2 came before 3? The question also extends to multiple readers: If there exists a reader that reads 2's value (and assume for simplicity that 2 comes after 1), do readers that read at the same time or later also read the same value, or can they potentially still see 1's value?

Comment: @RmbRT No. If 1 is followed by 2 which is followed by 3, 3 will read the value of 2, never of 1. But since only the read is atomic and not the subsequent processing, the value of 1 could be read (into a non atomic variable or expression),  but the process 3 could be set asleep and wake up after the process 2 was executed. This is why lock free is so difficult: there are a lot of potential scenario, but each thread can its own pace. so turning back your question to you: how would you know that 3 came after 2 if you’d read the value of 1 ?

Comment: I wouldn't know it. I was just assuming that there is an actual total order in which execution happens, not from the program's point of view, but from an all-knowing external observer's point of view. Since I read that only RMW operations are even guaranteed to see the very latest version of a variable, it seems to follow that non-RMW reads are not guaranteed to receive the latest value (from the observer's view), which is something I need. They only guarantee that once I read something, all side effects of that are visible too. So I think I have to use RMW to "hard fetch" reads.

Comment: @RmbRT wouldn’t an all-knowing observer just be another node that would read atomically the atomic?  But to come to the point: the rmw (compare&swap) seems to me the way to go, because when you just read atomically, the instruction after is no longer atomic so you’re no longer sure it’s the “latest” state that you act on (e.g. the simple if-statement on an atomic might branch on an obsolete value). so with separate reads and writes you’d always be in trouble. May I recommend Antony Williams’s book “C++ concurrency in action” that analyses such issues very well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it. My issue is that it seems that you have weaker guarantees on how recent the value you read using atomic load is. My understanding is that atomic loads just wait until propagation of the value, but RMWs actively fetch the value, so the propagation is forced and at least the instant you read it, you know it is the very latest (in wallclock time) value ever written to it. You seem to have no such guarantee on loads. I'll clarify my findings in the OP.

Comment: @RmbRT What concrete steps can an implementation take to "actively fetch a value"? How can you make "propagation" faster on common arch?

Comment: You can actively fetch a value using RMW (read-modify-write) operations, such as compare_exchange, fetch_or, etc. You can call such an operation in such a way that it does not modify the stored value. The value read by such an operation is guaranteed to be the most recent value, as far as I know. There seems to be no such guarantee for just atomic loads. You can also look at: https://github.com/RmbRT/atomic.git Maybe this helps you understand it better (relevant: the load_strong methods).

Comment: An atomic RMW *does* guarantee that its load side sees the "latest value" in the modification order or the atomic object.  That just means it's [serialized with writes and other RMWs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73212563), which is necessary for getting 1000 `fetch_add(1)` executions to result in a total modification of `+= 1000`.  See also [Does C++ sequential consistency guarantee reading the latest value stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74078058) and [Does atomic read guarantees reading of the latest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53032354)

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is surprising area.
First, an atomic read is not ordered after a write. I e reading a value does not mean that it were written before. Sometimes such read may ever see (indirect, by other thread) result of some subsequent atomic write by the same thread.

Sequential consistency are clearly about visibility and propagation. When a thread writes an atomic "sequentially consistent" it makes all its previous writes to be visible to other threads (propagation). In such case a (sequentially consistent) read is ordered in relation to a write.

Generally the most performant operations are "relaxed" atomic operations, but they provide minimum guarranties on ordering. In principle there is ever some causality paradoxes... :-)

Comment: Could you explain how those paradoxes happen?

Comment: The Alpha AXP is notorious for its very weak memory model. For example, suppose that initially `x=y=0`. Processor 1 does `x = x+1; y = x`. It is possible for processor 2 to calculate `y>x` as true (it reads `y` and gets 1, then reads `x` and gets 0), even though Processor 1 is the only one that modifies `x` and `y`, `y` was calculated from `x`, and processor 1 never sets `y` greater than `x`.

Comment: C++ MT semantics is pure BS. If values come from the future than UB can be from the future and no program semantic is ever defined. Please don't mention the future.

Comment: @RaymondChen But no CPU reads "in the future". They just reorder inevitable side effects, things that were guaranteed to happen soon can happen sooner. This isn't the same as "_Futurama_".

Comment: @curiousguy From Processor 2's point of view, the value of `y` came "from the future".

Comment: @RaymondChen From the inevitable, immediate future. Some badly specified high level semantic seems to allow events from a non immediate and hypothetical future. Then you might as well pretend that UB comes from the future, changing pointer values and causing UB.

Comment: [UB *does* come from the future](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)!

Comment: @RaymondChen In a deleted Q, I argue that UB makes the whole C/C++ unsound.