# C11 memory model -- two threads execute atomic_fetch_add followed by atomic_load -- what output is possible?

Tags: c, multithreading, language-lawyer, atomic, stdatomic

Consider the following test program, compiled and run on an implementation that fully implements C2011 atomics and threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <threads.h>

#if !ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE
#error "Program behavior is only interesting if atomic_int is lock-free."
#endif

static atomic_int var;

int inc_print(void *unused)
{
   atomic_fetch_add(&var, 1);
   printf(" %d", atomic_load(&var));
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    thrd_t thrd;
    if (thrd_create(&thrd, inc_print, 0) == thrd_success) {
        inc_print(0);
        thrd_join(&thrd, 0);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to convince myself that all of the following statements are true:

1. Each thread's `atomic_load` must observe the increment performed by that same thread, so it cannot read a zero.
2. Each thread's `atomic_load` may or may not observe the increment performed by the other thread. (The other thread might not get scheduled at all until after the atomic_load.) Therefore, it can read either a 1 or a 2.
3. The calls to `printf` are serialized *only* against each other.  Therefore, if one thread's `atomic_load` reads a 1 and the other thread's `atomic_load` reads a 2, either `1 2` or `2 1` may be printed.
4. It is possible for both `atomic_load`s to observe the increment performed by the other thread, so the output `2 2` is also possible.

What I'm not sure of, though: Is it possible for *neither* of the `atomic_load`s to observe the increment performed by the other thread?  That is, is the output `1 1` possible?

Also, does relaxing the memory model change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conclusions look correct to me.

The default `memory_order_seq_cst` guarantees this whole program executes [in a sequentially consistent manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#SC_for_DRF), since it's data-race free and doesn't use any non-SC atomics.  So the possible results are only interleavings of program-order.

This allows both increments then both loads, but one increment must come after the other, seeing its `1` result and writing a `2`.  And the load in that thread must come after it, so **at least one thread sees a `2`.**  The `1 1` result is impossible, the `2 2` result can happen.

---

**Relaxed atomics don't introduce any new possibilities here**; we can obtain the same guarantees from the rules for operations on the *same* atomic variable that apply regardless of the memory_order parameter.

- A consistent modification order for `var` exists, and a total of two atomic increments must do a total of `+=2`.  (Atomic RMWs are guaranteed to read the latest value for this reason, to make sure RMWs on the same object are serialized with each other, not both loading a 0 and writing a 1.  That wouldn't be an atomic increment.)
- A `load` after a `fetch_add` in the same thread must see its result or some later value in the modification order.  (In C++ this is [the write-read coherence guarantee](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#note-19), and sequenced-before (in the same thread) forcing ordering between two operations on the *same* atomic object.  edits welcome with a link to the equivalent language in the C11 standard.)

---

And yes, the `printf`s are ordered independently of the atomic modifications to `var`.  It effectively locks `stdout`.  If that works like the rules for C11 `mtx_lock`, that's like an `acquire` operation on the mutex, so it can be starting to take the lock before the increment or load complete.

Not that that's relevant; it's not required for the `2 1` output to be possible.  Even if locking was `seq_cst`, you could get to a state where neither printf had started, but all the atomics had finished.  With one thread having a 1 and the other a 2 as their temporaries.  Then it's just chance which gets to print first.