# Acqrel memory order with 3 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Lately the more I read about memory order in C++, the more confusing it gets. Hope you can help me clarify this (for purely theoretic purposes). Suppose I have the following code:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> val = { 0 };

std::atomic<bool> f1 = { false };
std::atomic<bool> f2 = { false };

void thread_1() {
  f1.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);

  int v = 0;
  while (!val.compare_exchange_weak(v, v | 1, 
                                    std::memory_order_release));
}

void thread_2() {
  f2.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);

  int v = 0;
  while (!val.compare_exchange_weak(v, v | 2, 
                                    std::memory_order_release));
}

void thread_3() {
  auto v = val.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  if (v & 1) assert(f1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
  if (v & 2) assert(f2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

The question is: can any of the assertions be false? On one hand, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) claims, `std::memory_order_release` forbids the reordering of both stores after exchanges in threads 1-2 and `std::memory_order_acquire` in thread 3 forbids both reads to be reordered before the first load. Thus, if thread 3 saw the first or the second bit set that means that the store to the corresponding boolean already happened and it has to be true.

On the other hand, thread 3 synchronizes with whoever released the value it has acquired from `val`. Can it happen so (in theory if not in practice) that thread 3 "acquired" the exchange "1 -> 3" by thread 2 (and therefore f2 load returns true), but not the "0 -> 1" by thread 1 (thus the first assertion fires)? This possibility makes no sense to me considering the "reordering" understanding, yet I can't find any confirmation that this cannot happen anywhere.

Comment: I believe the asserts cannot fire for the reasons you have given in the first paragraph.

Comment: `val.load` can only return 0,1,2 or 3. With the runtime checks that follow, the ordering of `f1` and `f2` (wrt their stores) is guaranteed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Neither assertion can ever fail, thanks to ISO C++'s "release sequence" rules.**  This is the formalism that provides the guarantee you assumed must exist in your last paragraph.

The only stores to `val` are release-stores with the appropriate bits set, done after the corresponding store to `f1` or `f2`.  So if `thread_3` sees a value with 1 bit set, it has definitely synchronized-with the writer that set the corresponding variable.

And crucially, they're each part of an RMW, and thus form a **release-sequence** that lets the acquire load in `thread_3` synchronize-with *both* CAS writes, if it happens to see `val == 3`.

(Even a `relaxed` RMW can be part of a release-sequence, although in that case there wouldn't be a happens-before guarantee for stuff before the relaxed RMW, only for other release operations by this or other threads on this atomic variable.  If `thread_2` had used `mo_relaxed`, the assert on `f2` could fail, but it still couldn't break things so the assert on `f1` could ever fail.  See also [What does "release sequence" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565650/what-does-release-sequence-mean) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

---

If it helps, I *think* those CAS loops are fully equivalent to `val.fetch_or(1, release)`.  Definitely that's how a compiler would implement fetch_or on a machine with CAS but not an atomic OR primitive.  IIRC, in the ISO C++ model, CAS failure is only a load, not an RMW.  Not that it matters; a relaxed no-op RMW would still propagate a release-sequence.

(Fun fact: [x86 asm `lock cmpxchg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) is always a real RMW, even on failure, at least on paper.  But it's also a full barrier, so basically irrelevant to any reasoning about weakly-ordered RMWs.)