# atomic thread fence: Why is there a data race on this non atomic variable? And does it matter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Let's say we have 2 threads. One producer and one consumer. We have the producer that produce a data, and the consumer that use this data. However the guard is not atomic !

```cpp
bool isDataReady = false;
int data = 0;

void Producer() {
  data = 42;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  isDataReady = true;
}

void Consumer() {
  while(!isDataReady);
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  assert(data == 42);
}
```

I wonder why is there a data race on `isDataReady`.
Normally, the correct code should be to use `relaxed` ordering on an atomic bool variable.

Is it because the write (transaction) to isDataReady could be not finished before the read? And even if it is the case, is it really an issue?

Comment: IIRC, fences ensure synchronization order of stores/loads. However, you still access the same memory location (`isDataReady` variable) at once from two threads where one thread updates it, which is a definition of data race (and UB in C++).

Comment: @DanielLangr if there is a data race (even if it is not a "problem"), it is an UB in C++?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Yes: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21.sentence-3.

Comment: You didn't mention the CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This data race is dangerous and you should care about eliminating it. It may not manifest due to your luck, but it will eventually cause a headache.

#### A bit longer

This code has problems due to a few issues:

1. While compiling `Consumer` compiler is not aware that `isDataReady` can change in background so it is perfectly reasonable to emit `while(!isDataReady)` an infinite loop or just nothing (due to [forward progress guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee), as was pointed out in comments).
2. If write and/or read to `bool` is not atomic (which is not the case on most platforms, yet is theoretically possible) any of reads can cause getting garbage data.
3. Memory fence with `std::memory_order_release` ensures that changes that happend in the thread will be visible after other thread calls fence with `std::memory_order_acquire` (at least in simplification). So, the change of bool variable may be invisible in other thread.
4. Due to superscalar architecture of modern processorss, **operations may be reordered in runtime by processor**. So order of memory writes in `Producer` visible from `Consumer` may be different than the one put in the code.

Comment: Because of the forward progress guarantee, it would be equally reasonable for the compiler to emit nothing at all rather than an infinite loop (I believe).

Comment: For 1), make `isDataReady` volatile fix the problem.
2) The volatile is not enough, and I need atomic operation.
3) The same, I need an atomic (since atomic operation are done in memory location), so the change of bool became visible in other thread.
4) Since I am using memory fencing, it is not really an issue.

Am I correct?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier AFAIK 1)y 2)y 3) and 4) yes, but you have to place memory fences properly.

Comment: @You I thought forward guarantee is important only for atomic, lock-free variables

Comment: @bartop In my code my memory fences are well placed, no? The "only issue" in my code is because of the data race on `isDataReady`

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Yup, just move first memory fence line down, and the second inside `do{}while` line above and it will be all fine

Comment: @bartop: Not quite, I think: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee

Comment: @bartop I am reading this article http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/acquire-release-fences . It seems that the atomic_thread_fence are placed exactly like I did. The only difference between his code and mine is its `isDataReady` is an atomic variable.
In this example, the intesting things is to not put an acquire release operation inside a loop, else we could just use an atomic_variable with relase/acquire operation. Since release/acquire operation are heavier than relaxed, using `atomic_thread_fence` should result in faster performance

Comment: @AntoineMorrier If you care about performance, you might be interested in non-blocking waiting (provided, e.g., by condition variables). Reading an atomic bool in a loop effectively blocks CPU (spin lock - busy waiting), which is useful only if you know that you cannot use that CPU (core) another way and that the waiting will be very short.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier BTW, to illustrate the endless-loop problem, the compiler really generates an infinite loop at the machine code level, see https://godbolt.org/z/PJztDp (`.L6: jmp .L6`). The only way to prevent it here would be to put the fence inside the loop. Or, better, to use `atomic<bool>`. Do not use `volatile` for what `atomic`s are for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8819095/580083.

Comment: Re, "bool is not atomic ... reads can [get] garbage data."  Are you saying that an assignment to a `bool` variable could be a compound operation that temporarily stores a value that is neither `true` nor `false` before it stores the final value? I suppose the language standard could _allow_ that behavior, but given how C++ was evolved from the "C" programming language, and given how conditional operations work in most CPU instruction architectures, I would be very surprised if any reasonable implementation actually worked in that way.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier, Re, "only difference...is its isDataReady is an atomic variable." That's not a trivial difference. The compiler must emit appropriate memory fence instructions in proximity to every use of an `atomic` variable.  That's part of what `atomic` means.

Comment: @SolomonSlow i know that is not a trivial difference at all. I know the difference between an atomic and a non atomic variable. Ton only is maybe misused. But the discussion was about to put or not to put the fence inside the loop :). That is why I take the liberty to say "only" ;)